# How to fix custom insertString function in C

Tags: c, string, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strLength(char *strP) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*(strP + i) != '\0') i++;
    return i; 
} 
// insert the second string into the first starting 
// at the specified index 
// if failure, do nothing
void insertString(char *str1P, char *str2P, int index) 
{
    int i = 0,
    str1Length = strLength(str1P), str2Length = strLength(str2P);

      *(str1P + str1Length + str2Length) = '\0';    
    while(i < (str1Length - index))
    {
        *(str1P + index + str2Length + i) = *(str1P + index + i);
          *(str1P + index + i) = *(str2P + i);
         i++;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    //insert
    char str8[20] = "the wrong son";

    insertString(str8, "per", 14 );
    printf("\nAfter insert1  = %s\n", str8);

    insertString(str8, "per", 10 );
    printf("After insert2  = %s\n", str8);

    insertString(str8, "You are ", 0);
    printf("After insert3  = %s\n\n", str8);
    return 0;
}
```

I am learning about pointers and strings in C for my Algorithms and Program Design class, and we were recently given this as part of an assignment. I have everything else complete, but I am still having trouble with the insertString function. The first two calls from main produce a desirable result, but the third seems to break. Could someone help me find what could be causing this?

Comment: It looks like you have a buffer overflow in your test code - change `char str8[20]` to e.g. `char str8[256]` perhaps ? There may be other bugs too, of course...

Comment: ALWAYS check sizes of your buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third call fails beacuse the size of str8 is 20. and third string insertion needs more memory than that allocated to str8[20].
So allocate more memory to support third string insertion or you can use `dynamic allocation` to string variable to have a general solution.